# Dual booting Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-xp

My laptop has 500gb hard disk in which for 250gb I installed Windows xp on C drive(primary partition). I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 in the remaing hard drive with dual boot option. When I am going to install Ubuntu it is showing something like

```
/boot
/boot/
```

Can anybody help me in this regard that where and how to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Yes...

here's how to do it-

When you boot the LIVE CD/USB for installation, you will get 3 options like the picture below- (windows 7 will be not be in your case, it will be xp)

[image: ubuntu along side windows 7]

for your Requirement,you should click on the 3rd option - Do something else.

That will take you to a partition table.

In the partition table you will see 2 partitions.
 - The 1st one will be c drive which has windows.You will be able to see it as NTFS file system.

- If both are NTFS,mostly the 1st partition will be C drive.

> keeping the size of the 2 partitions different e.g 230 and 270 will help you easily recognize your c drive because there are no labels like c or d there)

Then select that other drive.

**Get some free space to install :**

**Caution : Below steps is for deleting . Deleting a hard disk partition will make all files inaccessible everything in that partition, be sure to take back up if any.**

- Select that drive(other than the WINDOWS c DRIVE) from the partition table and click on `DELETE`. That partition will be deleted and you will see unallocated space.

**Caution : Below steps is for formatting. Formating a hard disk partition will permanently erase everything in that partition.**

Now,you can either directly make the complete partition as EXT4 for installing Linux or you can also add a SWAP partition.

> It is always recommended to add a SWAP area for better performance but only if your ram is below 8gb

**Step 1 : Create a `SWAP` partition**

1. Select the new unallocated space or free space, click on `add`.
2. Assign the space from that partition to SWAP AREA equal to double your ram.(e.g-for  1gb,swap area-2gb)
3. Select `SWAP AREA` from the file system drop down menu.
4. Make sure `Beginning` is selected in the partition `position drop` down menu.
5. Click on `add`.

[image]

**Adding root file system**

Now, after you have added the SWAP AREA,do this-

1. Select the remaining "Unallocated space" and click on ADD.
2. Select Ext4 Journaling file system from the file-system dropdown menu.
3. Select `Primary` from the partition type drop-down menu.
4. Select the mount point as `/` from the mount-point drop-down menu.
5. Select `beginning` from the Position drop-down menu.
6. Click on `add`.

[image: crate root file system]

After adding the partitions,from the table select the `ext4` partition you see and tick in the corresponding check-box(if not already ticked)
[image]

then Select INSTALL...

Comment: I updated your answer with pictures. If unhappy feel free to roll back. :)

Comment: thanx for the edit!! Gr8 wrk!