# I am getting boot error after installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, boot-failure

I am new user from window to Ubuntu. I just had installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. **I have 4 drives NTFS + 1 drive (c:).** C Drive is 50-GB. I don't want to remove other 4 drives which are on NTFS. I have deleted partition of C changes it to EXT4 file system.
**I think i am doing mistake in "Advance Partition Mode"...** Because i don't know, how to set "mount point" and "Primary OR Logical" options for 1 (50-GB) drive.. Can you tell me what i do now.

Note: **I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS twice**. every time i did fully format the drive. But the second time i get the boot error too.

Comment: This will help you → http://askubuntu.com/questions/139270/dual-booting-windows-and-ubuntu/139273

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created more than 4 partitions on NTFS you may not able to create additional partitions while installing Ubuntu along with Windows. You can try to select logical partition, while installing ubuntu then create ext4 and swap partition on ubuntu.

Comment: If there are four primary partitions on a physical drive with a "MS-DOS" partition table, it is not possible to add an extended partition. (An extended partition is a container for logical partitions; a logical partition cannot be added without there being, or without being able to create, an extended partition.)

Comment: My comment is kind of wrong, actually I had 3 partitions and then created all **logical** partitions for linux distros