# How to dual boot ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)
>   [Dual booting Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139270/dual-booting-windows-and-ubuntu)

I am building a computer and would like to dual boot these two OS's

Comment: @iSeth: that question talks about weird `/boot, /boot/` issues, so it's not a duplicate of this one. The answer posted there is relevant, so maybe edit that question to make it more generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Windows 7 first, then once that's installed and set up you can insert your Ubuntu LiveCd and boot from it. The Ubuntu installer will detect the Windows 7 installation and give you the option to install alongside it.

This is just a brief description, if you need help with the installation processes for either Windows 7 or Ubuntu there's plenty of guides online.

[Windows 7:](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/windows-7-clean-install-part-1.htm)

[Ubuntu:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

Comment: So when I boot up, this will give me the option to choose os? Also, does the disk need to be in all the time to run ubuntu?

Comment: Yes you'll get a screen similar to this but with Windows 7 options also [link]http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_fgqraly-g4/T5qvLogkr5I/AAAAAAAAAXE/i3gmuWCcK2c/s0/ubuntu-11.04+grub.png No it doesn't, once you have Ubuntu installed it will ask you to restart to finalise it. While restsrting it will prompt you to remove the disc and press enter. Ubuntu will function without the disc from this point on.

Comment: Which Ubuntu option would I choose? (from the link).              But Thanks very much!!! This really helped!

Comment: The very first option! The one with `(Recovery Mode)` after it is similar to booting into Windows Recovery. It's only really used if for some reaon you can't boot into the normal system! The `Linux 2.6.37-12-Generic` is just the Linux Kernel version.