# How to install ubuntu 12.04 on a system already having Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

I have a system Having hard disk of 300 GB. I have 4 partitions i.e C://(40GB), D://(80Gb), E://(90GB), F://(90GB).

I have installed Windows 7 in C: drive , now i need to install ubuntu 12.04 on D: drive.
Is it possible if yes then how should i do that ?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [Dual booting Windows and Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/139270/114818), [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1366/114818), [How do I set up a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/107538/114818). Please proceed by following these questions (and there are lots of others as well). If you get stuck anywhere come back and ask your question specific to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu 12.04 on windows system

Make bootable pen-drive or bootable compaq disc(CD) with Ubuntu 12.04

Follow the steps:

1. Attached Pen drive or CD on your commuter
2. De-fragment the disc space of D drive in windows
3. Restart your computer
4. When Black screen comes it will automatically take your bootable CD or pendrive if not press f11 to go to boot menu
5. After that Ubuntu started
6. Set it's time zone
7. Identify your partition of D drive on Ubuntu
8. Your Ubuntu installed successfully on your system.

In this way your Ubuntu will be installed. So each time when you start your computer it will be always ask for windows or Ubuntu.

Select Ubuntu from list.

Comment: Thank you Sumit, please elaborate 2nd point i mean to say how i  will fragment the disk space of drive D in windows .

Comment: @Sarvagya Pandey, Please follow this link for step 2 [http://windows.about.com/od/maintainandfix/ss/defragment_all.htm]

Comment: No need to de-fragment. After identifying the driver, he need to delete partition (this will delete all data) and recreate with file system `ext4`(or `ext3`) and mount point as `/`.

Comment: Some times it fails to identifying the drive without de-fragment. I have face an issue without defrag.

Comment: Hello Sumit how it will identify the drive d: or it will automatically identify the drive, should i have to delete the partition during installation of ubuntu or i have to delete the partition before installing ubuntu

Comment: No need to delete the partition, it'll automatically detect all the partitions on the drive select one of them(D drive). Allocate the space to Ubuntu from the free space of drive.